# How to convert a xml field to a table in sql?

Tags: sql-server

I have a XML column in a table that looks like this:

```
<word A="al"   B="h"   C="Ps" />
<word A="has"  B="es"  C="Pf" />
<word A="mom"  B="es"  C="Ph" />
```

I need to convert into table like this:

```
 word  | A  | B  | C
 ====================
   al  | A1 | B1 | C1
   has | A2 | B2 | C2
   mom | A3 | B2 | C3
```

I want to do by  a function  in SQL Server.

Thanks!

Comment: Your expected result does not seem to match the input you have. Can you explain a bit about how you want the values in the XML to be interpreted?

Comment: @Mikael he completely changed the question and the desired results. I've already been down-voted once because my output no longer matches what he's after. :-(

Comment: @AaronBertrand - And you have [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293391/how-to-update-a-xml-field-table-in-sql#comment13245007_10293391) that does **not** help explaining what is going on. But I do like the most [voted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10294146/569436) :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing on data type here, and also guessing that you didn't mean to convert `a1` -> `A1`, etc.

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(XMLFIELD XML);

INSERT @x SELECT '<word A="a1"  B="b1"  C="c1" />'
UNION ALL SELECT '<word A="a2"  B="b2"  C="c2" />'
UNION ALL SELECT '<word A="a3"  B="b2"  C="c3" />';

-- INSERT INTO dbo.OtherTable
SELECT 
  A = x.a.value('@A', 'varchar(32)'),
  B = x.a.value('@B', 'varchar(32)'),
  C = x.a.value('@C', 'varchar(32)')
FROM @x AS src
CROSS APPLY src.XMLFIELD.nodes('word') AS x(a);
```

Results:

```
A       B       C
------- ------- -------
a1      b1      c1
a2      b2      c2
a3      b2      c3
```

**EDIT**

And now that you've completely changed the question, making my answer look insane and completely unrelated to your question, let's try again. Once more I'm making some guesses here because you're not describing your logic or requirements very well. Does the B column increment every time you see a new value? Same with the C column? Is there any chance there are duplicates that *aren't* in consecutive rows?

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(XMLFIELD XML);

INSERT @x SELECT '<word A="al"   B="h"   C="Ps" />'
UNION ALL SELECT '<word A="has"  B="es"  C="Pf" />'
UNION ALL SELECT '<word A="mom"  B="es"  C="Ph" />';

;WITH y AS
(
  SELECT 
    word = x.a.value('@A', 'varchar(32)'),
    n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x.a.value('@A', 'varchar(32)')),
    B = x.a.value('@B', 'varchar(32)'),
    C = x.a.value('@C', 'varchar(32)')
  FROM @x AS src
  CROSS APPLY src.XMLFIELD.nodes('word') AS x(a)
)
SELECT word, 
    A = 'A' + RTRIM(n),
    B = 'B' + RTRIM((SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM y AS y2 WHERE n < y.n AND B <> y.B)),
    C = 'C' + RTRIM((SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM y AS y2 WHERE n < y.n AND C <> y.C))
FROM y 
ORDER BY word;
```

Results:

```
word   A    B    C
------ ---- ---- ----
al     A1   B1   C1
has    A2   B2   C2
mom    A3   B2   C3
```

If you want coherent answers that actually solve your problem, you should work on describing your problem well (and getting it right the first time, before a bunch of effort is spent trying to solve the wrong problem).

Comment: Really? Ok, so apply `UPPER()` to the three columns, e.g. `UPPER(x.a.value('@A', ...`

Comment: For the down-voter, please note that the OP completely changed the question. My response answered the original question correctly, with the exception that I didn't get the case right on the output.