# how to update a xml field table in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a XML column in a table that looks like this:

```
<word A="al"   B="h"   C="Ps" />
<word A="has"  B="es"  C="Pf" /> 
<word A="mom"  B="es"  C="Ph" />
```

I want to update this field like this:

```
<word A="al"   B="B1"   C="C1" /> 
<word A="has"  B="B2"  C="C1" /> 
<word A="mom"  B="B2"  C="C2" />
```

I want to do by a function in SQL Server.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to describe the logic behind the update.

Comment: I kind of understand the B1/B2 assignment, but the C1/C2 assignments make no sense to me. Can you please elaborate and explain where the coefficients for B and C come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mikael states you need to describe the logic behind the update. But for the expected output above, the following should work:

```
DECLARE @Words xml
SELECT @Words = '
<word A="al"   B="h"   C="Ps" />
<word A="has"  B="es"  C="Pf" />
<word A="mom"  B="es"  C="Ph" />'

SET @Words.modify('replace value of(/word[@A = "al"]/@B)[1] with "B1"')
SET @Words.modify('replace value of(/word[@A = "al"]/@C)[1] with "C1"')
SET @Words.modify('replace value of(/word[@A = "has"]/@B)[1] with "B2"')
SET @Words.modify('replace value of(/word[@A = "has"]/@C)[1] with "C1"')
SET @Words.modify('replace value of(/word[@A = "mom"]/@B)[1] with "B2"')
SET @Words.modify('replace value of(/word[@A = "mom"]/@C)[1] with "C2"')

SELECT @Words
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the "replace value of" in your XQuery. 
Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190675.aspx