# Shaping XML output of a SELECT statement on the inserted and deleted tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm capturing the contents of the `inserted` and `deleted` tables in a trigger and saving them as xml to a change log.

For inserts and deletes it straight forward. Just do a select on the corrisponding table and use `FOR XML` to convert it to xml.

Updates are turning out to be a little bit more tricky because you're merging data from two tables that essentially represent the *before* and *after* state of the `UPDATE`. Right now I'm using a `UNION` to combine the data from `inserted` and `deleted` into a single result set.

```
SELECT [Column1], [Column2]
FROM
    (SELECT [Column1], [Column2]
     FROM inserted
     UNION
     SELECT [Column], [Column2]
     FROM deleted) as Rows
FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS
```

The output looks something like:

```
<!-- Comments added for clarity. They don't appear in the actual output -->
<row> <!-- After -->
    <Column1>Bar</Column1>
    <Column2>Ipsum</Column2>
</row>
<row> <!-- Before -->
    <Column1>Foo</Column1>
    <Column2>Lorem</Column2>
</row>
```

What I would like the output to be is:

```
<row>
    <Column1>
        <Before>Foo</Before>
        <After>Bar</After>
    </Column1>
    <Column2>
        <Before>Lorem</Before>
        <After>Ipsum</After>
    </Column2>
</row>
```

Or maybe

```
<row>
    <Column1 Before="Foo" After="Bar" />
    <Column2 Before="Lorem" After="Ipsum" />
</row>
```

But I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Any ideas?

Note: Some of our clients are still using SQL Server 2005 so using the new change tracking really isn't an option yet.

Comment: Do you have a primary key you can join the tables on?

Comment: Yes. I need to apply this trigger to multiple tables but they all have an identically defined primary key.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. I have tested with regular table (not in a trigger). And assumed the PK is called `ID`.

```
select d.Column1 as 'Column1/Before',
       i.Column1 as 'Column1/After',
       d.Column2 as 'Column2/Before',
       i.Column2 as 'Column2/After'
from inserted as i
  inner join deleted as d
    on i.ID = d.ID
for xml path('row')
```

Answer (score 2):

I've done exactly this for an audit trail solution, and ran into the same issue. My resolution was as follows:

As you mentioned, inserts and deletes are easy. When a new record is inserted, we don't store any XML, because the field values included in the insert are the current values in the live table. When a record is deleted, you store the state of the record as it was at the point that it was deleted in the XML field.

Updates posed a bit of a problem, because I didn't want to have to store the data twice for each record (i.e. the before AND after). Then it occurred to me that I only need to store the "Before" data (i.e. the deleted table), because the "After" is stored in the original table itself, or the following audit trail record against the same record. It does make life a bit more difficult when reconstructing the trail, but certainly makes sense from a storage perspective.

In other words, Let's say a record is added at 01:00:00. The record is updated at 02:00:00 and 02:30:00, and deleted at 03:00:00. Your audit trail would look something like:

```
AuditKey Timestamp  RecordType    RecordKey   AuditType    XML
1        01:00:00   MyTable       213         I            NULL
2        02:00:00   MyTable       213         U            XML1
3        02:30:00   MyTable       213         U            XML2
4        03:00:00   MyTable       213         D            XML3
```

Using a self-join, you can get two consecutive records, showing the before and after state of the record in MyTable. The audit trail for our sample record is as follows:

```
From AuditKey 1 and 2: Record was inserted at 01:00, with the field values XML1
From AuditKey 2 and 3: Record was updated at 02:00, and changed from XML1 to XML2
From AuditKey 3 and 4: Record was updated at 02:30, and changed from XML2 to XML3
From AuditKey 4 and NULL: Record was deleted at 03:00
```

If the last record was not a deletion, but another update, then the last line of the audit trail would read:

```
From AuditKey 4 and NULL: Record was updated at 03:00, and changed from XML3 to the field values in the live table.
```

This approach has worked well for us, to the point that we are able to reconstruct a record to any point in history. Taking this approach one step further, the XML stored against each record only records those fields whose values have changed. This does mean that we can't immediately determine what was changed between two points in history without iterating through all of the logs in between. However, since these logs are viewed very infrequently, it was a priority to make them efficient rather than quick. This depends on the requirements of your specific environment.

A sample of the query I used looks something like this:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Timestamp]) AS RowNum,
    AuditKey, [Timestamp], AuditType, XML FROM AuditTrail 
    WHERE RecordType = 'MyTable' AND RecordKey = 213)
SELECT t1.Timestamp, t1.AuditType, t1.XML AS FromXML, 
    CASE WHEN t2.XML IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE RecordKey = 213 FOR XML AUTO) ELSE t2.XML END AS ToXML
FROM cte t1 LEFT JOIN cte t2 ON t2.AuditKey = t1.AuditKey + 1
WHERE t2.AuditType <> 'D'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT      CAST('
<row>
  <Column1 Before="' + i.Column1 + '" After="' + d.Column1 + '" />
  <Column2 Before="' + i.Column2 + '" After="' + d.Column2 + '" />
</row>' AS xml)
FROM        inserted i
INNER JOIN  deleted d ON i.ID = d.ID
```

Comment: You have a cross join between `inserted` and `updated`. Works fine if you only update one row at a time. Not so great if the update statement affected more than one row because the trigger is called once for the update statement not once for each updated row.

Comment: @Mikael: Good point. I'm not that familiar with triggers to be honest, I was just demonstrating how to shape the xml.

Comment: Me too :). The "magic tables" in a trigger are `deleted` and `inserted`.

Comment: BTW, I really like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10294146/569436). It's the best one can do with so little information.

Comment: Why thank you :). I always like to provide some code where possible, regardless of how poor the question is. Even if it doesn't answer the question directly it may help point the poster in the right direction.